# How to change language in Darktable from Ubuntu

Tags: language-support, localization, darktable

Darktable language inexplicably changed itself to Czech

The darktable FAQ says it uses the OS's language.. but my OS's language is English. **So where could it be getting the idea it should be Czech?** It was in English when I first installed it and I haven't done anything new or Czechy since.

More importantly: **How do I set the language of Darktable to English from Ubuntu?** All the instructions I can find are for Windows.

Thank you

[edit: using Fossa]

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Please edit you question and show the output of the `locale` terminal command.

Comment: Hmm.. Ok. As you say, nothing there which indicates Czech. I would guess that there is a display language setting in the darktable application which overrides the locale. If you don't find that, I wonder if it makes a difference if you start it with: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 darktable` (The difference compared to the workaround in your answer is that `en_US.UTF-8` is the correct locale name.)

Comment: Good idea! unfortunately when I try that it opens in Czech again. It's still opening in Czech by default when I open it normally, but when I use the workaround I posted below that one session opens in English.

Comment: Then I suppose the proper way is that you look for a language setting in the application. Or just keep using the workaround, but my objections to it still stand. ;)

Comment: Believe it or not, looking for a language setting in the application was the very first thing I tried and it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

OK I found something that worked for me, here we go:

```
LANG=<language_code> && darktable
```

Replace <language_code> with the desired language code. For English:

```
LANG=en_US && darktable
```

I would still appreciate input on what in my OS is telling programs they shouldn't be in English (this happened to me before with Portuguese!)

Comment: `en_US` has either not been generated on your system, in which case `LANG=en_US` is effectively the same as `LANG=C`. Or it has been generated, in which case `LANG=en_US` may enable latin1 encoding, which is probably not your intention. So I find the answer misleading to users, and downvoted it. It would fit better as workaround as part of the question, so you may want to move it there.

Comment: Darktable was in Czech and then I ran that and now it's in English, and I couldn't find any other solution anywhere.. and my OS is in UK English. Are you saying that "LANG=C && darktable" would be better?

Comment: No, it would probably be just as bad. Better to figure out the explanation. I asked for additional info with that purpose directly under your question.

Comment: Thanks, done. Nothing about cz in there, Portuguese and English (The clock for Ireland was wrong when I installed the OS so I had to set it to Lisbon time)